# How do I put the selected core-menu item into a custom polymer element?

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to encapsulate a `paper-dropdown` in a `paper-button`. To do this, I made a custom element, `paper-dropdown-holder`:

```html
<polymer-element name="paper-dropdown-holder" extends="paper-button" relative on-tap="{{toggle}}">
<template>
<shadow></shadow>
<content></content>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
    toggle: function() {
        if (!this.dropdown) {
            this.dropdown = this.querySelector('paper-dropdown');
        }
        this.dropdown && this.dropdown.toggle();
    }
});
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

and I'm using it in the page like:

```
<paper-dropdown-holder raised tabindex="0" class="unpadded">
        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown" flex>
            <core-menu class="menu" selected="0">
                <paper-item><a href="#writing">Writing</a></paper-item>
                <paper-item><a href="#blog">Blog</a></paper-item>
                <paper-item><a href="#art">Art</a></paper-item>
            </core-menu>
        </paper-dropdown>
</paper-dropdown-holder>
```

My problem is deciphering [The documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-menu) to figure out how to automatically put the text of the currently-selected menu item into the `paper-dropdown-holder`.

My first attempt was to just use a standard `paper-dropdown-menu`, but I couldn't as easily style that like a `paper-button`. **Is there any way to do this that's not (for lack of a better term) hacky?** I'd love if the answer would keep to the Polymer philosophies.

Bonus challenge: **How do I set default text like "choose section"?**

Comment: I think my post has answered your question, unless you have any notes about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of awesome things of Polymer is it's open source... that said you could learn how to implement new element based on already existing elements....

If you have a look at `paper-dropdown-menu` source you could easily make something like it but with `paper-button` as a "control".

**So**

1. The new element should extend `core-dropdown-base` not
   `paper-button`.
2. To make that element logically working you could do that with
   some help of `paper-dropdown-menu` by binding (`core-overlay-open`,
   `core-activate`, `core-select`) events to the according handlers.
   (the actual binding happens in `core-dropdown-base` in `dropdown`
   getter which called inside `attached` event listener.

To put them together:

```
<polymer-element name="paper-dropdown-holder" extends="core-dropdown-base" relative>
  <template>
    <div>
      <paper-button raised on-tap="{{toggle}}">{{selectedItemLabel || label}}</paper-button>
      <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
      Polymer('paper-dropdown-holder', {
        publish: {
          label: 'Select an item',
        },

        selectedItemLabel: '',

        overlayListeners: {
          'core-overlay-open': 'openAction',
          'core-activate': 'activateAction',
          'core-select': 'selectAction'
        },

        activateAction: function(e) {
          this.opened = false;
        },

        selectAction: function(e) {
          var detail = e.detail;
          if (detail.isSelected) {
            this.selectedItemLabel = detail.item.label || detail.item.textContent;
          } else {
            this.selectedItemLabel = '';
          }
        }

      });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/MWalid/pen/WbGPYP).